# PHP laravel don't select duplicate fields shared in two tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my project I want to query orders. every food have a category and every category have a parent. so my problem is some orders have two type parent category. like Indian food and italian food in one order. I used select multiple element. and parent categories are shown inside it. one another item is all. so when user selects all parent categories the orders that have two type of categories like explained above it's shows more than 1 in table and I have no idea how to select only one of this duplicate fields.
my query code is :

```
if (isset($subset) && $subset!=""){
        $query->leftJoin('z_food_orders','z_food_orders.order_id','=','z_orders.id')
                ->leftJoin('z_foods','z_food_orders.food_id','=','z_foods.id')
                ->leftJoin('z_food_cats','z_foods.cat_id','=','z_food_cats.id')
                ->leftJoin('z_res_subset','z_food_cats.parent_id','=','z_res_subset.id');
        if (count($subset) == 1){
            $query->where('z_res_subset.id',$subset);
        }else{
            $query->whereIn('z_res_subset.id',$subset);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i don't familiar with laravel but you can make order by desc which came from main table, it will not duplicate it

Comment: thanks but it's not works for me.

Comment: how z_food_orders have 2 types of category, it is only have food_id, I guess you have a missing in your tables design?

Comment: can you make simple demo or just show strukture table ? how many table you join it, i suggest you using manual query first in phpmyadmin then change as laravel model,

Comment: as I explained every food have a category like pizza and every category have a parent like italian food. so for instance when  a user submits a new order that have one food from italian category and another food from indian category it have two categories in one order.

Comment: @hosseinahmadi and in this case your result will be 2 category of course so what is problem?

Comment: no the problem is two rows shown for one order. because the foods are from two different categories.